# Binding process to multiple processors on Sun Solaris OS

Tags: binding, process, solaris, processor

I have a server running Solaris OS. I want to bind number of processors to a certain process. I have tried following commands:

1) ps: to get process id.

```
bash-3.00$ ps -ef | grep java
bileng 10708 10695   3 12:20:59 pts/1       0:26 /opt/billengine/jdk1.6.0_29/bin/sparcv9/java -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xloggc:./jb
```

2) psrinfo: to get the processor id.

```
bash-3.00$ /usr/sbin/psrinfo
0       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:17
1       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
2       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
3       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
4       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
5       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
6       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
7       on-line   since 11/04/2013 16:22:18
```

3) pbind: to bind process to the processor.

I want to bind processor number 4 to 7 to a process id say 10708. Hence, I tried following command:

```
bash-3.00$ /usr/sbin/pbind -b 4-7 10708       
/usr/sbin/pbind: invalid processor ID 4-7
```

4) However, when I try binding single processor id to a process id, then it works:

```
bash-3.00$ /usr/sbin/pbind -b 4 10708
process id 10708: was not bound, now 4
```

5) But my requirement is **to bind multiple processors to a single process id**.

I tried exploring all the man pages and documents, but unable get the clue.

Can anyone please suggest some pointers on the same.

Thanks.

Comment: The original command `pbind -b 4-7 10708` will work in Solaris 11.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool for doing this in Solaris is `psrset`

You create a processor set with

```
 psrset -c 4-7
```

This will return the ID of the new processor set

```
 created processor set ps_id
```

Then you can bind a process to a processor set with

```
 psrset -b ps_id pid
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks a lot. The processor set is created with `psrset`. However, I require a root privileges for the same. Else it throws following `error: /usr/sbin/psrset: could not create processor set: Not owner`. Is there anyway to create processor set from non-root user?

Comment: you need to have sys_res_config in your /etc/user_attr and if zones are configured you have to be logged into the global zone.

Answer (score 2):

In Solaris 11.2, you can do this with the processor_affinity(2) system call. A blog entry describing this can be found here: https://blogs.oracle.com/observatory/entry/multi_cpu_binding_mcb and there's a man page of course:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36872/processor-affinity-2.html